# ¿como puedo crear una validacion de datos?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

hola que tal estoy haciendo un código el cual me permita registrarme, iniciar sesión y editar los datos ingresados por el usuario
ya tengo echa el inicio de sesión

```
<?php
 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
 $db = mysqli_select_db($link,"datos_usuario") or die ("<h2>Error de Conexion</h2>");

 if (isset($_POST['nombre'])){
     $nombre =$_POST['nombre'];
     $apellido =$_POST['apellido'];
     $contraseña =$_POST['contraseña'];
     $rcontraseña =$_POST['rcontraseña'];
     $telefono =$_POST['telefono'];
     $edad =$_POST['edad'];
     $email =$_POST['email'];

 }
 $req = (strlen($nombre)**strlen($apellido)*strlen($contraseña)*strlen($telefono)*strlen($edad)*strlen($email));
 if ($contraseña != $rcontraseña) {
    echo ' <script language="javascript">alert("Atencion, las contraseñas no coinciden");</script> ';
}

 mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO datos VALUES ('','$nombre','$apellido','$contraseña','$telefono','$edad','$email')")

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
    .contenedor
    {
        width:1340px;
        height:1000px;
        line-height:400px;      
        text-align:center;
    }
    .contenedor>span {
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        line-height:normal;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="registro.php">

    <div class='contenedor'>
        <span>felicidades ya estas registrado<br></span>
        <td><label><input type="submit" value="inicia sesion"></input></label></td>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

pero en lo que concierne con el inicio de sesión y cambiar lo datos no he logrado entender como hacerlo
no se como hacer que compare los datos ingresados del usuario con los datos de la base de datos y no se como hacer que el usuario pueda modificar su información alguien me podría ayudar por favor

Answer (score 0):

te voy a dar un ejemplo con sentencias preparadas para que protejas tu código de sql injection:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");

 // Te aconsejo que valides que lleguen todos los datos, ya que estás
 // validando solo el nombre, además, debes validar que los datos
 // lleguen sin estar vacíos para que tengas certeza que hay algo
 // en ellos por medio del servidor.

 if (isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['apellido']) && isset($_POST['contraseña']) && isset($_POST['rcontraseña']) && isset($_POST['telefono']) && isset($_POST['edad']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
     $nombre =$_POST['nombre'];
     $apellido =$_POST['apellido'];
     $contraseña =$_POST['contraseña'];
     $rcontraseña =$_POST['rcontraseña'];
     $telefono =$_POST['telefono'];
     $edad =$_POST['edad'];
     $email =$_POST['email'];

 }

 $req = (strlen($nombre)**strlen($apellido)*strlen($contraseña)*strlen($telefono)*strlen($edad)*strlen($email));

 if ($contraseña != $rcontraseña) {
    echo ' <script language="javascript">alert("Atencion, las contraseñas no coinciden");</script> ';
} else { //Debes hacer el insert dentro del else para que se inserten si la contraseña es válida
 $stmt = $link->prepare('INSERT INTO datos VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)');
 $stmt->bind_param('ssssss',$nombre,$apellido,$contraseña,$telefono,$edad,$email);
 // Las 6 "s" de arriba preparan los datos como un string, si tienes datos que sean solo numeros debes colorcar una "i" siguiendo el orden de inserción.
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();
 $link->close();
}

?>
```

Con lo anterior, haces la inserción de los datos al registrarse. Ahora, al momento de iniciar sesión debes hacer otro formulario donde pidas ciertos datos, como el email y contraseña, validas que lleguen los datos y haces un `select` a la bd. Algo como esto:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['contraseña'])) {
  //Creas las variables
  $email_post = $_POST['email'];
  $contraseña_post = $_POST['contraseña'];

  //Traes los datos de la bd
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
  $stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT nombre,apellido,contraseña,telefono,edad,email FROM datos WHERE email=? AND contraseña=?');
  $stmt->bind_param('ssssss',$email_post,$contraseña_post);
  $stmt->bind_result($nombre_user,$apellido_user,$contraseña_user,$telefono_user,$edad_user,$email_user);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) { //Verificamos que existe en la bd
     $stmt->fetch(); //Mostramos los datos y los guardamos en variables de sesión para usarlos más adelante
     $_SESSION['nombre_user'] = $nombre_user;
     $_SESSION['apellido_user'] = $apellido_user;
     $_SESSION['contraseña_user'] = $contraseña_user;
     $_SESSION['telefono_user'] = $telefono_user;
     $_SESSION['edad_user'] = $edad_user;
     $_SESSION['email_user'] = $email_user;

     //Aquí colocas lo que quieres hacer cuando se inicie sesión. Por ejemplo:
     echo ' <script language="javascript">alert("Ha iniciado sesión correctamente");</script> ';
     //Agrega esto al final de tu código para finalizar la sentencia y liberar los datos obtenidos
     $stmt->free_result();
     $stmt->close();
     $link->close();
  } else { //Si no existe
    echo "Debe registrarse para iniciar sesión.";
  }
}

?>
```

Ya tienes el inicio de sesión. Ahora, si quieres editar todos los datos, debes hacer un formulario, preferiblemente en otra página donde valides que la persona que está visitando esa url haya iniciado sesión previamente y sean los datos de una determinada persona, para eso los `$_SESSION` de arriba.

En donde hagas tu formulario, utiliza los `session` para traer los datos hasta tu formulario si lo deseas, si no, puedes eliminar los `session` (conserva el de $email_user), los datos del `select` (conserva email y contraseña) y esta linea de código: `$stmt->bind_result(...)`. Cuando se envíen los datos editados, realiza un `UPDATE` a la bd para actualizarlos:

```
<?php

 if (isset($_POST['nombre']) && isset($_POST['apellido']) && isset($_POST['contraseña']) && isset($_POST['rcontraseña']) && isset($_POST['telefono']) && isset($_POST['edad']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
   $nombre =$_POST['nombre'];
   $apellido =$_POST['apellido'];
   $contraseña =$_POST['contraseña'];
   $rcontraseña =$_POST['rcontraseña'];
   $telefono =$_POST['telefono'];
   $edad =$_POST['edad'];
   $email =$_POST['email'];

   if ($contraseña != $rcontraseña) {
      $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
      $email_u = $_SESSION['email_user'];
      $stmt = $link->prepare('UPDATE datos SET nombre=? AND apellido=? AND contraseña=? AND telefono=? AND edad=? AND email=? WHERE email="'.$email_u.'"');
      $stmt->bind_param('ssssss',$nombre,$apellido,$contraseña,$telefono,$edad,$email);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->close();
      $link->close();
      echo ' <script language="javascript">alert("Datos actualizados");</script> ';
   } else {
      echo "Las contraseñas deben coincidir";
   }
} else {
   echo "Datos incompletos";
}
```

Ya con eso puedes hacer lo que necesitas. Te recomiendo que revises el manual de php: https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-stmt.php para conocer más sobre sentencias preparadas.